# Accessing JSON object in servlet

Tags: java, json, jsp

[image: Personal Details page]

Here, as shown in figure, I want to access email id and contact number for a particular name. My problem is that I have alternate email id and contact number too for each name. there may be many names.

I have done it in following way, but could not get exact data at servlet.
I have used seperate arrays for name, email and contact number.Still failing.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

My code is :

studentEnquiry.jsp

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $('#getdata').click(function() {

            alert("hiii")
            alert($('#enqDate').val())


            var name = [];
            var email = [];
            var contact = [];

            name.push($('#sname').val())

             alert($('#sname').val())

                //if($('#enqName').val())
    //{





            //}
            /* 

            name for loop

            for(i=1;i<4;i++){
                alert('hi')

                    if($('#sname'+i).val())
                    {

                    name.push($('#sname'+i).val());
                    alert($('#sname'+i).val())

                   }//if end     */







                 email.push($('#enqEmail').val());
                 alert($('#enqEmail').val())
                    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
                    {   
                        if($('#enqEmail'+i).val())
                        {

                            email.push($('#enqEmail'+i).val());
                            alert($('#enqEmail'+i).val())
                        }//email if end 
                    }//for end  








                    alert($('#enqCont').val())

                        contact.push($('#enqCont').val());
                        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
                        {   

                        if($('#enqCont'+i).val())
                        {
                            //contact = contact.push($('#enqCont'+i).val);
                             contact.push($('#enqCont'+i).val);
                            alert($('#enqCont'+i).val())

                        //contact if end

                    }//for end
    }//name end

            $.ajax({

                url : '/StudentEnquiryController',
                type : 'post',
                datatype : 'json',
                data : {

                enquirydata : JSON.stringify({  
                    "enDate" : $('#enqDate').val(),
                    "enCity" : $('#enqCity').val(),
                    "enClg"  : $('#enqColg').val(),
                    "enDept"  : $('#enqDept').val(),
                    "enDomain" : $('#enqDomain').val(),
                    "enTech" : $('#enqTech').val(),
                    "enTeamsz" : $('#enqTeamSz').val(),
                    "enName" : name,
                    "enEmail" : email,
                    "enCont" : contact                  
                })
                },

                success : function() {
                    alert($('#enqDate').val())
                },

                error : function(){

                    alert('error')
                }

                });

        });
    });
$(function() {

        $('#getdata').click(function() {

            alert("hiii")
            alert($('#enqDate').val())


            var name = [];
            var email = [];
            var contact = [];

            name.push($('#sname').val())

             alert($('#sname').val())

                //if($('#enqName').val())
    //{





            //}
            /* 

            name for loop

            for(i=1;i<4;i++){
                alert('hi')

                    if($('#sname'+i).val())
                    {

                    name.push($('#sname'+i).val());
                    alert($('#sname'+i).val())

                   }//if end     */







                 email.push($('#enqEmail').val());
                 alert($('#enqEmail').val())
                    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
                    {   
                        if($('#enqEmail'+i).val())
                        {

                            email.push($('#enqEmail'+i).val());
                            alert($('#enqEmail'+i).val())
                        }//email if end 
                    }//for end  








                    alert($('#enqCont').val())

                        contact.push($('#enqCont').val());
                        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
                        {   

                        if($('#enqCont'+i).val())
                        {
                            //contact = contact.push($('#enqCont'+i).val);
                             contact.push($('#enqCont'+i).val);
                            alert($('#enqCont'+i).val())

                        //contact if end

                    }//for end
    }//name end

            $.ajax({

                url : '/StudentEnquiryController',
                type : 'post',
                datatype : 'json',
                data : {

                enquirydata : JSON.stringify({  
                    "enDate" : $('#enqDate').val(),
                    "enCity" : $('#enqCity').val(),
                    "enClg"  : $('#enqColg').val(),
                    "enDept"  : $('#enqDept').val(),
                    "enDomain" : $('#enqDomain').val(),
                    "enTech" : $('#enqTech').val(),
                    "enTeamsz" : $('#enqTeamSz').val(),
                    "enName" : name,
                    "enEmail" : email,
                    "enCont" : contact                  
                })
                },

                success : function() {
                    alert($('#enqDate').val())
                },

                error : function(){

                    alert('error')
                }

                });

        });
    });
</script>
```

studentEnquiry servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("in StudentEnquiryController");

        try {
            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("enquirydata"));


            System.out.println(jsonobj.toString());

            String date = (String) jsonobj.get("enDate"); 
            System.out.println("date is "+date);

            JSONArray jsonnamearray = (JSONArray) jsonobj.get("enName"); 

            JSONArray jsonemailarray = (JSONArray) jsonobj.get("enEmail");




            JSONArray jsoncontactarray = (JSONArray) jsonobj.get("enCont");



            System.out.println("contacts is :"+(JSONArray) jsonobj.get("enCont"));

            for(int i=0;i<jsonnamearray.length();i++)
            System.out.println("names are :"+jsonnamearray.getString(i));


            for(int i=0 ; i<jsonemailarray.length();i++)
                System.out.println("emails are :"+jsonemailarray.getString(i));


            for(int i=0 ; i<jsoncontactarray.length();i++)
                System.out.println("contacts are :"+jsoncontactarray.getString(i));


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you post one or more illustrative examples of the strings you are getting for the "enquirydata" variable (i.e. example json strings)?

Comment: now,I am able to get data for one record (i.e. name),how to get it for multiple records(i.e. names)